# Windows 10 Git bash : cat: /etc/version: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, git, windows-10, 64-bit

I am running Git bash on Windows 10 64 bit. It was running fine perfectly today , but now it shows up with a weird message and the formatting and colors are all messed up:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I uninstalled Git bash and deleted the folder in C:/Program Files/Git , and rebooted, but the message still shows

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to fix it. I just had to navigate to my C:\Users\YourUserNameHere directory and delete my .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .bash_history profiles. Then I ran the unins000.exe located inside the C:\Program Files\Git directory to uninstall Git Bash. I then manually deleted the folder right after and rebooted. I then reinstalled Git Bash.

I SSH'd into a device right before, so I believe something during that period added those bash profiles there, and gitbash was automatically loading them and when I uninstalled, it left those files there.